# Intent filter works on emulator but not on device

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter, android-10.0

I'm creating a custom intent filter which will open my app when I tap a file with a certain file extension (`.myextension` in this case.) The intent-filter is below. This currently works perfectly every time I open a `.myextension` file from my emulator. However, when I try it from my device, it no longer works.

On my device, when I tap a `.myextension` file in the Files browser app, I see `Unable to preview file.` instead of automatically opening the app. I've tried opening the file from quite a few locations (Files app, GDrive, Downloads folder, Slack/Gmail, both internal storage and SDCard.) I'm using Android 10 on both my emulator and my device.

```
<intent-filter android:label="My App">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data
        android:scheme="content"
        android:mimeType="*/*"
        android:host="*"
        android:pathPattern=".*\\.myextension" />
</intent-filter>
```

I've also tried replacing that `data` tag/adding a second tag with this block but it doesn't seem to help:

```
<data
    android:scheme="file"
    android:mimeType="*/*"
    android:host="*"
    android:pathPattern=".*\\.myextension" />
```

Am I missing something obvious? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This currently works perfectly every time I open a .myextension file from my emulator.

It will fail much of the time, as it is not really tied to an emulator versus a device.

> However, when I try it from my device, it no longer works.

A `content` `Uri` is not required to have a file extension, just as an `https` URL is not required to have a file extension. Much of the time, a `content` `Uri` will not have a file extension, and such a `Uri` will not match your `<intent-filter>`.

`ACTION_VIEW` is mostly for files with a widely-recognized MIME type.

> I've also tried replacing that data tag/adding a second tag with this block but it doesn't seem to help

`file` `Uri` values have been generally banned since Android 7.0.

Comment: You're right -- I misunderstood how these work. I've re-written the flow to launch a file chooser from inside the app where you can then select the file that you need. Thanks!

Comment: @Nate please can you share your solution i have  the same problem, Thanks

Answer (score -2):

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

     <data android:scheme="file" />
     <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.myextension" />
     <data android:pathPattern="/*.*\\.myextension" />
     <data android:pathPattern="/*.*\\..*\\.myextension" />
     <data android:pathPattern="/*.*\\..*\\..*\\.myextension" />
     <data android:pathPattern="/*.*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.myextension" />
     <data android:pathPattern="/*.*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.myextension" />
     <data android:pathPattern="/*.*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.myextension" />
     <data android:pathPattern="/*.*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.myextension" />
     <data android:pathPattern="/*.*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.myextension" />
     <data android:host="*" />
</intent-filter>

Though it doesnt work in some of the file managers Better first try in ESExplorer.
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! Unfortunately this didn't fix it. I don't think it is related to the path pattern because I'm using a file with a very simple name: `test.myextension`. And also it is currently opening on the emulator which means pathPattern is working already to some extent.

Comment: Can you give me more insight on what is not working ? is it the popup to select the app is not showing or in your app you are not getting the intent?