# Open specific file extention with the app

Tags: java, android, react-native

I have an app that create a custom file, when open the file in the device file manager it should run the app and the file should be copied to the bundle directory.
I followed this tutorial:
https://dev-yakuza.github.io/en/react-native/open-file-with-app/

everything work fine on the emulator (android version 9), but it doesn't work on my device (with android version 6.0.1), it just open the app but doesn't copy the file.

my `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />                                               
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />                                              
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DOWNLOAD_WITHOUT_NOTIFICATION" />

<application
  android:name=".MainApplication"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
  android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
  android:allowBackup="false"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
  <activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE"/> 
    </intent-filter>
    <!-- custom file start -->
    <intent-filter
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:label="@string/app_name">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.EDIT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <!-- change custom file extension -->
        <data
          android:mimeType="*/*"
          android:host="*"
          android:pathPattern=".*\\.wallkami"
        />
    </intent-filter>
    <!-- custom file end -->
  </activity>
  <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
</application>
```

`MainActivity.java`:

```
package com.wallkami;
import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;
import com.facebook.react.ReactActivityDelegate;
import com.facebook.react.ReactRootView;
import com.swmansion.gesturehandler.react.RNGestureHandlerEnabledRootView;

import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {

  /**
   * Returns the name of the main component registered from JavaScript. This is used to schedule
   * rendering of the component.
   */
  @Override
  protected String getMainComponentName() {
    return "wallkami";
  }

 @Override
 protected ReactActivityDelegate createReactActivityDelegate() {
   return new ReactActivityDelegate(this, getMainComponentName()) {
     @Override
     protected ReactRootView createRootView() {
      return new RNGestureHandlerEnabledRootView(MainActivity.this);
     }
   };
 }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Uri data = getIntent().getData();
        if(data != null) {
            try {
                importData(data);
            }catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("File Import Error", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    private void importData(Uri data) {
        final String scheme = data.getScheme();

        if (ContentResolver.SCHEME_CONTENT.equals(scheme)) {
            try {
                ContentResolver cr = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver();
                InputStream is = cr.openInputStream(data);
                if(is == null) return;

                String name = getContentName(cr, data);

                PackageManager m = getPackageManager();
                String s = getPackageName();
                PackageInfo p = m.getPackageInfo(s, 0);
                s = p.applicationInfo.dataDir;

                InputStreamToFile(is, s + "/files/opened.wallkami");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("File Import Error", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    private String getContentName(ContentResolver resolver, Uri uri){
        Cursor cursor = resolver.query(uri, null, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int nameIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME);
        if (nameIndex >= 0) {
            return cursor.getString(nameIndex);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    private void InputStreamToFile(InputStream in, String file) {
        try {
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(file));

            int size = 0;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

            while ((size = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                out.write(buffer, 0, size);
            }

            out.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("MainActivity", "InputStreamToFile exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

NOTE: I'm not good with native code XD

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58295174/115145

Comment: @CommonsWare Intent filter work on device, it open the app but doesn't copy the file.

Comment: "Intent filter work on device" -- it will not work on most devices and for most situations, as file extensions are rarely used for `content` `Uri` values. Beyond that, do not use `dataDir`. Instead, for [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/06/storage-situation-internal-storage.html), use `getFilesDir()` on a `Context`.

Comment: @Nameer please can you share your solution?